# Outputting JSON data to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I'm using a jQuery call back function to receive a JSON object from  insert.php to insert.js file.

The object is being receive correctly but when I try to output it to the screen

I am getting an error :

`"TypeError:a is undefined"` jQuery.js

**JSON**

```
{"result":{"name":"asdasd ","location":"asdasdas","email":"asd"}}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="InsertEventForm" action="insert.php" method="post">
  <p>Event Name:<br />
    <input id="name"  type="text"  name="name"  />
  </p> 
  <p>Event Location :<br />
    <input id="location" type="text" name="location"  />
  </p>
  <p>Email:<br />
    <input type = "email" name="email" />
  </p> 
  <p>
    <button id="insertSubmit">Save</button></a>
  </p>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#insertSubmit").click( function() {
  $.post( $("#InsertEventForm").attr("action"), $("#InsertEventForm :input").serializeArray(), function(info){ 
    var output='<ul>';
    $.each(info.result,function(key,val){
      output+='<li>';
      output+='<h3>Event Name:' + val.name + '</h3>'; 
      output+='<p>Location:' + val.location + '</p>'; 
      output+='<p>Contact:'+ val.email + '</p>'; 
      output+='</li>';
      console.log(output)                 
    });  
    output+='</ul>';
    $('#result').html(output); // Out put the update div
  });  
  clearInput();//******clears the fields  *//
});

$("#InsertEventForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Sorry json file is actual {"result":{"name":"asdasd ","location":"asdasdas","email":"asd"}}

Comment: It seems to me the error is not from the exposed code. Could you wrap that in jsFiddle?

Comment: in your html snipped there's a closing </a> Tag without any opening <a> Tag. May be that's a problem?

Comment: @user3488945 Don't put code in comments. Use the **edit** link below your question to modify and correct your question. Then you can delete the comment. This will allow others reading your question so they can help you.

Comment: you obviously did not post your full code. you seem to use a variable called `a` which is not defined. try initialising this variable using `var a;`.

Comment: The problem is not there, hope that helps

Comment: the undefined a is being referenced from  line 2 of the Jquery.js file

Comment: I've tried pulling in jquery through the cdn but i get the same issues.

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle of what I think you're trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/s1nprjge/2/ The email address was invalid, so I fixed that.  I didn't see any place to display the results, so I added a `result` div. For testing, can you make the results display somewhere other than `console.log`? The code certainly isn't working. Is `$('#result').html(output);` proper jQuery?